# Monitor EC2 instances per tag with CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

Is it possible to monitor EC2 instances based on their tag name? 
I have a number of instances that start from similar spot fleets and they all share the same set of tags (including name).
I want to create some alerts and a dashboard for these instances but there is no straightforward way

Answer (score 0):

If you set an alert on an EC2 Instance, the alert is applied only on that particular instance id. So even if you create alert on EC2 instance that share the same tag name, alerts are applicable only for that instance id, EC2 Instances with the same tag won't be receiving the alerts.